# To or For with any adjective

Tags: prepositions

in these sentences i can't spot a difference, to me they both have the same meaning:

> It is **late to do** that
>
> I am **good to be** here
>
> I am **good for being** here
>
> It is **late for doing** that

Comment: What is the source? Are you writing these, or did you find them somewhere?

Comment: I just wrote them 

Comment: Could you explain what you’re trying to say with each sentence? For example, “I am good for being here” means “being here shows that I am a good person”. Is that what you meant? Or did you mean “being here makes me happy”?

Answer (score 1):

The usual forms of these are pretty much set phrases.

> It is **too late** to do that.
>   **It is** good to be here.

The other two don't make sense as written. Not necessarily wrong, but most people wouldn't say them. Possibly OK in an expanded context.